# JQuery Find All Elements with Duplicate Values for Form Validation val() function not returning user entered values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML form on an admin site. I need to return all input elements that have one or more input values that are the exact same value. However, the following code is not working. $(this).val() is always returning null for any of the values I enter. However, if I load an existing form with values prefilled, the $(this).val(); works correctly.

```
if ($('.nickname-input:visible').valid() && $('.funding-input:visible').valid()) {
            $('.nickname-input:visible').each(function () {
                var nickname = $(this).val(); 
                if ($('input[name="' + nickname + '"]').length == 2) {
                    showNotification("Error", 'danger', "Account Nicknames must be unique", 'fas fa-exclamation-circle');
                    return false; 
                }
            });
            alert("valid");
}
```

Comment: Console log $(this) to see what it's picking up

Comment: Hard to tell without the HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrectly targeting the name attribute and not the value attribute.

Resolved Code:

```
$('.nickname-input').each(function () {
            var nickname = $(this).val();
            if ($('input[value="' + nickname + '"]').length == 2) {
                showNotification("Account Nicknames must be unique", 'danger', "Error", 'fas fa-exclamation-circle');
                return false;
            }
});
```